# quadrant sectioned map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am unable to find any documentation on how to do what has been accomplished on the map in the page of the link below. Does anyone know how this was accomplished?

[Link to interactive map](http://www.johnstonanddaniel.com/interactive-map-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technology is called quadtree and quadkey. It uses a z curve to reduce the dimension complexity. Each quadrant is a part of a bigger map. The entire map is made of 21^4 tiles. Each tile has it unique address. You can also look for a geohash or Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog. I've written a hilbert curve quadkey script in php at phpclasses org (hilbert-curve). It uses a script to transform a lat/lng pair to WSG 84 datum and compute a quadkey. For example you can use it for a fast proximity lookup.